# Detect Errors using TortoiseGitProc.exe to initiate pull in a console application

Tags: tortoisegit

I'm programmatically calling tortoiseGitProc.exe to perform a pull of source code files.  The process works fine in that I get the TortoiseGit Pull dialog and all is well. What I cannot do is determine in my console application whether or not the pull process succeeded or failed. I'd like to show a dashboard style indication that the process worked or not.  Yes, you can tell on the dialog but how does my application know if the process worked or not?

Comment: TortoiseGit is not designed to be scriptable or automatable.

Why not use the CLI directly instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm finding that out.  Most of my team uses TortoiseGit so I wanted to make a utility that helps everyone stay on the same page with our sort of complicated build process (of which pulling is the first step).  I think though that if I interrogate the process exit code, it might give me the answer I'm looking for (using Process to launch the TortoiseGit commands).

Comment: The exit code of TortoiseGit mostly only shows whether the last dialog was closed via ok or cancel/abort.